# Is there any way to include Search Address lookup to a custom aura component which is used to override the standard New record functionality?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When you Enable Maps and Location in an Enterprise org you can have a Search Address lookup to Search addresses using google maps,

My question is do we have a way to include this lookup to a custom aura component which is used to override the standard New record functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightning:inputAddress component has a showAddressLookup which you can set to True to show the Google maps powered address search

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputAddress/specification

Comment: Jeff, Edited the question.

Comment: Yes, setting the showAddressLookup to true on the lightning:inputAddress component will show that search lookup. See the linked specification